Find an audit trail for username in SQL Server?
I need to get an audit trail for user deletion, meaning real username instead of dbo, must give me real username. How can I achieve this on my query, please assist.
2024-04-10 00:16:14.907 Update  Mduduzi
2024-04-10 02:38:50.863 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-04-10 03:30:59.623 Update  Mduduzi
2024-04-10 03:47:34.153 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-04-10 04:42:46.137 Update  Mduduzi
2024-04-10 04:59:38.040 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-04-10 05:13:46.473 Update  Mduduzi
2024-04-10 05:47:04.370 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-04-10 06:46:52.193 Update  Reginald
2024-04-10 07:06:28.527 Insert  Reginald
2024-04-10 07:47:16.840 Update  Reginald
2024-04-10 08:44:34.400 Insert  Reginald
2024-04-10 09:02:20.407 Update  Reginald
2024-04-10 11:56:56.933 Update  Rebaone
2024-04-10 10:24:29.450 Insert  Reginald
2024-04-10 10:50:13.930 Update  Reginald
2024-04-10 11:55:45.253 Insert  Reginald
2024-04-10 12:21:05.370 Update  Reginald
2024-04-10 13:39:32.300 Insert  Reginald
2024-04-10 14:18:52.290 Update  Reginald
2024-04-10 14:51:48.753 Insert  Reginald
2024-04-10 15:03:48.230 Update  Reginald
2024-04-10 17:04:15.033 Insert  Reginald
2024-04-10 17:23:44.267 Update  Reginald
2024-04-10 18:14:54.943 Update  Mduduzi
2024-04-10 17:31:22.863 Insert  Reginald
2024-04-10 18:00:28.870 Update  Reginald
2024-04-10 19:28:35.037 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-04-10 20:12:18.810 Update  Mduduzi
2024-04-10 22:19:02.393 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-04-10 23:14:09.123 Update  Mduduzi
2024-04-11 08:02:19.070 Update  Elsie
2024-04-11 08:21:33.913 Insert  Reginald
2024-04-11 08:57:54.210 Update  Reginald
2024-04-11 10:06:30.173 Insert  Reginald
2024-04-11 10:24:40.307 Update  Reginald
2024-04-11 11:09:36.983 Insert  Reginald
2024-04-11 11:49:45.190 Update  Reginald
2024-04-11 12:14:28.700 Insert  Reginald
2024-04-11 12:42:47.670 Update  Reginald
2024-04-11 13:17:44.347 Insert  Reginald
2024-04-11 13:36:39.847 Update  Reginald
2024-04-11 15:05:42.510 Insert  Reginald
2024-04-11 15:41:39.040 Update  Reginald
2024-04-11 16:22:50.140 Update  Rebaone
2024-04-11 15:56:44.137 Insert  Reginald
2024-04-11 16:15:10.617 Update  Reginald
2024-04-11 16:23:39.340 Update  Rebaone
2024-04-11 16:26:45.667 Update  Reginald
2024-04-11 16:53:06.570 Insert  Reginald
2024-04-11 17:20:07.733 Update  Reginald
2024-04-11 20:38:38.243 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-04-11 21:04:14.400 Update  Mduduzi
2024-04-11 21:57:46.573 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-04-11 22:18:19.067 Update  Mduduzi
2024-04-11 23:27:07.000 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-04-11 23:49:45.140 Update  Mduduzi
2024-04-17 08:55:15.080 Update  Elsie
2024-04-12 08:08:55.327 Insert  Vincent
2024-04-12 08:58:20.693 Update  Vincent
2024-04-12 09:59:36.060 Insert  Vincent
2024-04-12 10:35:05.383 Update  Vincent
2024-04-12 14:47:41.443 Insert  Vincent
2024-04-12 15:13:47.860 Update  Vincent
2024-04-12 16:28:21.480 Insert  Vincent
2024-04-12 16:41:41.950 Update  Vincent
2024-04-12 17:08:49.310 Insert  Vincent
2024-04-12 17:35:32.463 Update  Vincent
2024-04-12 19:26:06.530 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-04-12 19:45:34.010 Update  Mduduzi
2024-04-12 20:41:42.877 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-04-12 21:00:13.347 Update  Mduduzi
2024-04-12 21:01:23.603 Update  Mduduzi
2024-04-12 22:23:10.510 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-04-12 22:54:06.770 Update  Mduduzi
2024-04-13 01:39:33.103 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-04-13 01:54:19.990 Update  Mduduzi
2024-04-15 11:40:41.350 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-04-15 11:51:43.160 Update  Mduduzi
2024-04-15 22:04:31.867 Insert  Reginald
2024-04-15 23:03:02.547 Update  Reginald
2024-04-16 01:52:54.223 Insert  Reginald
2024-04-16 02:01:54.037 Update  Reginald
2024-04-16 02:48:53.920 Insert  Reginald
2024-04-16 03:20:17.827 Update  Reginald
2024-04-16 09:29:00.090 Update  Matlhodi
2024-04-16 09:29:07.713 Update  Matlhodi
2024-04-16 09:29:32.180 Update  Matlhodi
2024-04-16 08:39:57.360 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-04-16 13:24:00.067 Update  Matlhodi
2024-04-16 13:24:03.897 Update  Matlhodi
2024-04-16 13:24:28.533 Update  Matlhodi
2024-04-16 12:49:19.020 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-04-16 14:59:28.450 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-04-16 15:15:26.290 Update  Mduduzi
2024-04-16 17:17:13.447 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-04-16 17:32:11.543 Update  Mduduzi
2024-04-16 22:39:57.030 Insert  Vincent
2024-04-16 23:09:37.950 Update  Vincent
2024-04-17 12:10:40.383 Update  Mduduzi
2024-04-17 03:39:40.713 Insert  Vincent
2024-04-17 07:47:13.260 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-04-17 07:50:39.757 Update  Mduduzi
2024-04-17 08:26:53.670 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-04-17 08:45:29.280 Update  Mduduzi
2024-04-17 09:40:35.760 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-04-17 16:14:33.793 Update  Mduduzi
2024-04-17 12:34:34.733 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-04-17 12:41:06.087 Update  Mduduzi
2024-04-17 12:37:20.780 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-04-17 12:49:56.410 Update  Mduduzi
2024-04-17 12:47:53.907 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-04-17 13:12:19.283 Update  Mduduzi
2024-04-19 07:39:52.960 Update  Elsie
2024-04-17 13:20:16.877 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-04-17 13:21:49.603 Update  Mduduzi
2024-04-17 15:25:27.393 Update  Matlhodi
2024-04-17 14:11:54.260 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-04-17 14:40:58.260 Update  Mduduzi
2024-04-17 15:16:13.967 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-04-17 15:30:07.440 Update  Mduduzi
2024-04-17 16:35:43.690 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-04-17 16:52:37.097 Update  Mduduzi
2024-04-17 18:40:21.150 Insert  Vincent
2024-04-17 18:51:44.100 Update  Vincent
2024-04-17 21:10:59.057 Insert  Vincent
2024-04-17 21:30:24.460 Update  Vincent
2024-04-17 23:40:07.513 Update  Vincent
2024-04-17 22:57:58.013 Insert  Vincent
2024-04-17 23:16:50.887 Update  Vincent
2024-04-18 07:25:04.200 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-04-18 07:46:37.130 Update  Mduduzi
2024-04-18 08:39:14.273 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-04-18 08:59:08.527 Update  Mduduzi
2024-04-18 09:33:11.207 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-04-18 10:45:43.937 Update  Mduduzi
2024-04-18 18:37:48.793 Insert  Vincent
2024-04-18 18:47:58.830 Update  Vincent
2024-04-18 19:48:22.670 Insert  Vincent
2024-04-18 20:21:36.067 Update  Vincent
2024-04-18 21:34:28.873 Insert  Vincent
2024-04-18 21:53:45.183 Update  Vincent
2024-04-19 00:09:19.990 Update  Vincent
2024-04-19 00:00:44.883 Insert  Vincent
2024-04-19 09:56:11.227 Insert  Reginald
2024-04-19 10:01:40.383 Update  Reginald
2024-04-19 10:16:57.257 Insert  Rebaone
2024-04-19 10:29:05.067 Delete  dbo // need to find out who not this real username for deletion
2024-04-19 10:20:24.750 Insert  Rebaone
2024-04-19 10:29:13.737 Delete  dbo
2024-04-19 10:24:13.570 Insert  Rebaone
2024-04-19 10:24:50.220 Update  Rebaone
2024-04-19 10:59:55.453 Update  Rebaone
2024-04-19 11:03:41.930 Update  Rebaone
2024-04-19 10:31:52.650 Insert  Rebaone
2024-04-19 10:32:42.560 Delete  dbo
2024-04-19 10:40:53.883 Insert  Rebaone
2024-04-19 11:02:39.090 Update  Rebaone
2024-04-19 11:02:43.840 Update  Rebaone
2024-04-19 10:43:56.147 Update  Rebaone
2024-04-19 11:03:13.340 Update  Rebaone
2024-04-19 10:51:18.287 Insert  Rebaone
2024-04-19 10:52:49.403 Update  Rebaone
2024-04-19 10:52:57.730 Update  Rebaone
2024-04-19 11:18:14.660 Insert  Reginald
2024-04-19 11:54:46.017 Update  Reginald
2024-04-19 15:27:56.090 Insert  Reginald
2024-04-19 15:39:11.150 Update  Reginald
2024-04-19 15:29:42.080 Insert  Reginald
2024-04-19 15:41:56.677 Update  Reginald
2024-04-19 16:11:25.107 Insert  Reginald
2024-04-19 16:43:52.237 Update  Reginald
2024-04-19 16:35:19.563 Insert  Reginald
2024-04-19 17:06:59.690 Update  Reginald
2024-04-19 17:06:37.770 Insert  Reginald
2024-04-19 17:15:18.440 Update  Reginald
2024-04-19 18:58:17.583 Insert  Vincent
2024-04-19 19:36:56.913 Update  Vincent
2024-04-19 21:48:03.843 Insert  Vincent
2024-04-19 22:02:37.710 Update  Vincent
2024-04-19 23:00:02.227 Insert  Vincent
2024-04-19 23:12:07.027 Update  Vincent
2024-04-22 07:47:01.110 Update  Elsie
2024-04-19 23:40:00.167 Insert  Vincent
2024-04-19 23:57:38.850 Update  Vincent
2024-04-22 12:29:12.397 Update  Matlhodi
2024-04-22 09:00:08.970 Insert  Vincent
2024-04-22 09:34:21.013 Update  Vincent
2024-04-24 06:16:38.967 Update  Reginald
2024-04-22 10:40:09.417 Insert  Vincent
2024-04-24 06:25:41.733 Update  Vincent
2024-04-24 06:46:10.693 Update  Vincent
2024-04-22 12:39:14.730 Insert  Vincent
2024-04-22 14:28:14.180 Update  Vincent
2024-04-22 14:50:49.053 Update  Vincent
2024-04-22 16:13:07.043 Insert  Vincent
2024-04-22 16:25:04.147 Update  Vincent
2024-04-22 18:39:54.577 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-04-22 19:19:53.020 Update  Mduduzi
2024-04-22 21:23:44.487 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-04-22 22:02:59.060 Update  Mduduzi
2024-04-22 22:57:04.570 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-04-22 23:18:58.240 Update  Mduduzi
2024-04-23 00:04:09.627 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-04-23 00:45:46.190 Update  Mduduzi
2024-04-23 02:56:49.570 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-04-23 03:14:31.943 Update  Mduduzi
2024-04-23 04:41:48.040 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-04-23 05:05:55.650 Update  Mduduzi
2024-04-23 05:40:42.080 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-04-23 06:11:55.687 Update  Vincent
2024-04-23 09:45:43.237 Insert  Vincent
2024-04-23 10:04:08.993 Update  Vincent
2024-04-23 11:05:29.450 Insert  Vincent
2024-04-23 11:11:42.973 Insert  Vincent
2024-04-23 17:19:34.607 Update  Vincent
2024-04-23 12:47:00.003 Insert  Vincent
2024-04-23 13:09:17.063 Update  Vincent
2024-04-23 14:19:28.603 Insert  Vincent
2024-04-23 14:40:23.020 Update  Vincent
2024-04-23 18:58:56.170 Insert  Reginald
2024-04-23 19:31:59.160 Update  Reginald
2024-04-23 20:15:35.730 Insert  Reginald
2024-04-23 20:52:10.000 Update  Reginald
2024-04-23 21:50:45.340 Insert  Reginald
2024-04-23 22:15:52.093 Update  Reginald
2024-04-24 00:01:03.833 Insert  Reginald
2024-04-24 00:19:37.090 Update  Reginald
2024-04-24 08:32:19.413 Insert  Vincent
2024-04-24 08:53:23.160 Update  Vincent
2024-04-25 07:55:44.197 Update  Elsie
2024-04-24 09:46:01.740 Insert  Vincent
2024-04-24 13:59:58.490 Update  Vincent
2024-04-24 15:09:19.137 Update  Vincent
2024-04-25 11:08:35.467 Update  Vincent
2024-04-24 11:50:46.013 Update  Rebaone
2024-04-24 11:34:34.797 Insert  Vincent
2024-04-24 11:37:27.390 Update  Vincent
2024-04-24 11:51:38.820 Update  Vincent
2024-04-24 11:53:17.903 Update  Vincent
2024-04-25 11:17:37.717 Update  Matlhodi
2024-04-25 11:18:04.480 Update  Matlhodi
2024-04-24 11:50:36.733 Update  Rebaone
2024-04-24 11:39:11.720 Insert  Vincent
2024-04-24 11:39:17.533 Update  Vincent
2024-04-24 11:40:19.183 Update  Vincent
2024-04-24 11:40:36.167 Update  Vincent
2024-04-24 11:51:20.590 Update  Vincent
2024-04-24 12:28:09.560 Insert  Vincent
2024-04-24 12:38:33.290 Update  Vincent
2024-04-24 13:59:49.740 Insert  Vincent
2024-04-24 14:09:53.450 Update  Vincent
2024-04-24 15:50:08.883 Insert  Vincent
2024-04-24 16:15:07.240 Update  Vincent
2024-04-24 18:29:14.160 Insert  Reginald
2024-04-25 04:20:03.173 Update  Reginald
2024-04-24 18:41:23.450 Insert  Reginald
2024-04-24 19:27:51.477 Update  Reginald
2024-04-25 00:31:57.307 Insert  Rebaone
2024-04-25 00:32:22.583 Update  Rebaone
2024-04-25 00:34:12.997 Update  Reginald
2024-04-25 04:27:06.650 Insert  Reginald
2024-04-25 04:45:39.020 Update  Reginald
2024-04-26 08:21:01.787 Update  Elsie
2024-04-25 08:24:41.860 Insert  Vincent
2024-04-25 11:01:02.143 Update  Vincent
2024-04-25 11:09:07.697 Update  Vincent
2024-04-25 10:40:23.293 Insert  Vincent
2024-04-25 11:15:22.117 Update  Vincent
2024-04-25 11:18:09.180 Insert  Vincent
2024-04-25 11:40:08.680 Update  Vincent
2024-04-25 11:40:50.863 Update  Vincent
2024-04-25 11:41:10.380 Update  Vincent
2024-04-25 12:30:22.163 Update  Rebaone
2024-04-25 12:14:08.100 Insert  Vincent
2024-04-25 12:33:45.593 Insert  Rebaone
2024-04-25 12:39:25.497 Update  Rebaone
2024-04-25 12:40:38.177 Update  Vincent
2024-04-25 13:46:01.220 Insert  Matlhodi
2024-04-25 13:46:54.183 Update  Matlhodi
2024-04-25 13:47:47.443 Update  Matlhodi
2024-04-25 13:48:47.690 Update  Matlhodi
2024-04-25 13:49:34.527 Update  Matlhodi
2024-04-26 04:08:04.057 Update  Reginald
2024-04-25 14:35:44.253 Insert  Vincent
2024-04-25 15:27:49.267 Insert  Vincent
2024-04-25 15:45:59.160 Update  Vincent
2024-04-26 05:26:56.677 Insert  Reginald
2024-04-26 05:48:55.310 Update  Reginald
2024-04-26 11:29:43.307 Insert  Vincent
2024-04-26 11:44:59.520 Update  Vincent
2024-04-26 12:36:29.893 Insert  Matlhodi
2024-04-26 12:36:49.347 Update  Matlhodi
2024-04-26 12:43:35.320 Update  Matlhodi
2024-04-26 13:59:22.087 Update  Vincent
2024-04-29 11:39:22.507 Update  Elsie
2024-04-29 11:41:16.090 Update  Elsie
2024-04-26 15:06:56.343 Update  Rebaone
2024-04-26 14:48:30.157 Insert  Vincent
2024-04-26 14:59:38.040 Update  Vincent
2024-04-26 17:19:31.203 Update  Vincent
2024-04-26 15:51:26.720 Insert  Vincent
2024-04-26 16:34:36.160 Update  Vincent
2024-04-26 18:20:53.007 Update  Reginald
2024-04-26 17:27:39.050 Insert  Vincent
2024-04-26 21:50:50.380 Insert  Reginald
2024-04-26 22:21:07.657 Update  Reginald
2024-04-30 08:06:46.610 Update  Elsie
2024-04-29 09:26:44.157 Insert  Reginald
2024-04-29 10:06:33.713 Update  Reginald
2024-04-29 11:07:55.343 Insert  Reginald
2024-04-29 11:42:22.630 Update  Reginald
2024-04-29 12:30:08.373 Update  Reginald
2024-04-29 11:51:18.107 Insert  Reginald
2024-04-29 12:13:12.723 Update  Reginald
2024-04-29 12:14:49.213 Update  Reginald
2024-04-29 12:15:12.350 Update  Reginald
2024-04-30 00:58:12.347 Insert  Vincent
2024-04-30 01:20:34.563 Update  Vincent
2024-04-30 01:13:44.350 Insert  Vincent
2024-04-30 02:10:45.377 Update  Vincent
2024-04-30 07:35:10.940 Update  Elsie
2024-04-30 04:45:41.300 Insert  Vincent
2024-04-30 05:07:21.600 Update  Vincent
2024-04-30 08:05:15.950 Insert  Reginald
2024-04-30 08:14:58.897 Update  Reginald
2024-04-30 08:35:03.493 Insert  Reginald
2024-04-30 09:12:05.587 Update  Reginald
2024-04-30 09:33:46.077 Insert  Reginald
2024-04-30 10:01:27.013 Update  Reginald
2024-04-30 10:33:25.837 Insert  Reginald
2024-04-30 11:09:23.287 Update  Reginald
2024-04-30 11:22:28.190 Insert  Reginald
2024-04-30 11:58:52.140 Update  Reginald
2024-04-30 12:31:48.890 Insert  Reginald
2024-04-30 12:44:04.440 Update  Reginald
2024-04-30 12:46:14.000 Insert  Reginald
2024-04-30 12:57:58.350 Update  Reginald
2024-04-30 13:00:59.750 Insert  Reginald
2024-04-30 13:07:21.727 Update  Reginald
2024-04-30 22:04:36.440 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-04-30 22:26:23.673 Update  Mduduzi
2024-05-01 01:07:34.530 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-05-01 01:26:11.403 Update  Mduduzi
2024-05-01 09:46:11.937 Insert  Reginald
2024-05-01 09:59:00.067 Update  Reginald
2024-05-01 12:01:29.533 Insert  Reginald
2024-05-01 12:21:48.507 Update  Reginald
2024-05-01 15:37:43.040 Insert  Reginald
2024-05-01 15:49:52.463 Update  Reginald
2024-05-01 17:11:41.453 Insert  Reginald
2024-05-01 17:38:39.940 Update  Reginald
2024-05-02 08:07:18.673 Insert  Reginald
2024-05-02 08:30:50.833 Update  Reginald
2024-05-02 08:36:10.857 Update  Reginald
2024-05-02 08:33:24.793 Insert  Reginald
2024-05-02 08:35:37.657 Update  Reginald
2024-05-09 11:59:40.530 Update  Elsie
2024-05-02 10:30:21.267 Insert  Reginald
2024-05-02 15:46:40.257 Update  Reginald
2024-05-02 10:41:35.450 Insert  Reginald
2024-05-02 15:37:41.230 Update  Reginald
2024-05-02 11:36:48.180 Insert  Reginald
2024-05-02 12:25:41.283 Update  Reginald
2024-05-02 13:29:16.647 Insert  Reginald
2024-05-02 14:04:51.100 Update  Reginald
2024-05-02 15:06:05.730 Insert  Reginald
2024-05-02 15:27:17.770 Update  Reginald
2024-05-02 15:53:20.573 Insert  Reginald
2024-05-02 16:10:06.003 Update  Reginald
2024-05-02 21:41:22.480 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-05-02 22:10:38.327 Update  Mduduzi
2024-05-03 00:09:46.247 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-05-03 01:15:15.853 Update  Mduduzi
2024-05-03 05:09:01.180 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-05-03 06:06:01.800 Update  Reginald
2024-05-03 09:35:24.560 Update  Elsie
2024-05-03 07:32:51.403 Insert  Reginald
2024-05-03 07:52:45.890 Update  Reginald
2024-05-09 12:00:16.107 Update  Elsie
2024-05-03 09:31:35.203 Insert  Reginald
2024-05-03 12:41:23.103 Update  Reginald
2024-05-03 10:35:23.293 Insert  Reginald
2024-05-03 10:49:23.770 Update  Reginald
2024-05-03 10:39:06.013 Insert  Reginald
2024-05-03 10:48:09.040 Update  Reginald
2024-05-03 15:15:56.747 Insert  Reginald
2024-05-03 15:35:43.143 Update  Reginald
2024-05-09 12:01:21.100 Update  Elsie
2024-05-03 15:17:56.547 Insert  Rebaone
2024-05-03 15:19:06.680 Update  Rebaone
2024-05-03 15:25:10.660 Update  Reginald
2024-05-03 16:49:58.233 Insert  Reginald
2024-05-03 17:06:00.787 Update  Reginald
2024-05-03 19:08:02.840 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-05-03 19:51:10.627 Update  Mduduzi
2024-05-03 20:23:16.017 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-05-03 21:51:59.087 Update  Mduduzi
2024-05-03 22:08:40.943 Insert  Rebaone
2024-05-03 22:09:25.923 Update  Rebaone
2024-05-03 23:31:43.600 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-05-03 23:52:22.827 Update  Mduduzi
2024-05-04 01:01:10.583 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-05-04 01:25:09.870 Update  Mduduzi
2024-05-04 02:39:48.667 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-05-04 02:53:17.020 Update  Mduduzi
2024-05-04 05:54:17.557 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-05-04 06:19:13.947 Update  Reginald
2024-05-04 09:24:30.487 Insert  Reginald
2024-05-04 09:42:25.180 Update  Reginald
2024-05-04 09:53:46.817 Insert  Reginald
2024-05-04 10:10:46.610 Update  Reginald
2024-05-04 10:38:49.443 Insert  Reginald
2024-05-04 11:02:09.573 Update  Reginald
2024-05-04 12:14:30.370 Insert  Reginald
2024-05-04 12:27:23.160 Update  Reginald
2024-05-04 12:40:57.487 Insert  Reginald
2024-05-04 12:54:49.780 Update  Reginald
2024-05-04 15:03:32.773 Insert  Reginald
2024-05-04 15:13:35.750 Update  Reginald
2024-05-06 09:21:11.123 Update  Matlhodi
2024-05-06 09:11:01.740 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-05-06 09:15:16.270 Update  Mduduzi
2024-05-06 11:34:54.550 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-05-06 12:01:08.063 Update  Mduduzi
2024-05-06 11:41:42.977 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-05-06 11:58:04.457 Update  Mduduzi
2024-05-07 08:05:08.083 Update  Elsie
2024-05-06 11:57:50.427 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-05-06 14:01:03.167 Update  Mduduzi
2024-05-06 16:22:41.850 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-05-06 16:33:22.460 Update  Mduduzi
2024-05-06 17:26:02.767 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-05-06 17:42:03.220 Update  Mduduzi
2024-05-06 18:41:36.947 Insert  Reginald
2024-05-06 18:56:37.397 Update  Reginald
2024-05-06 18:59:19.020 Update  Reginald
2024-05-06 20:17:34.587 Insert  Reginald
2024-05-06 20:34:46.020 Update  Reginald
2024-05-06 21:43:08.400 Insert  Reginald
2024-05-06 22:08:51.353 Update  Reginald
2024-05-07 08:41:23.527 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-05-07 08:52:16.637 Update  Mduduzi
2024-05-07 08:45:19.703 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-05-07 08:54:44.253 Update  Mduduzi
2024-05-08 07:14:22.027 Update  Elsie
2024-05-07 09:36:22.227 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-05-07 13:13:04.613 Update  Mduduzi
2024-05-07 12:00:26.773 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-05-07 12:05:19.467 Update  Rebaone
2024-05-07 12:12:38.863 Update  Rebaone
2024-05-07 12:15:27.587 Update  Rebaone
2024-05-07 12:18:21.263 Update  Rebaone
2024-05-07 12:13:01.280 Update  Rebaone
2024-05-07 12:18:05.283 Update  Rebaone
2024-05-07 12:18:08.627 Update  Rebaone
2024-05-07 12:19:28.913 Update  Rebaone
2024-05-08 06:59:10.720 Update  Elsie
2024-05-07 12:31:08.237 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-05-07 12:52:06.593 Update  Mduduzi
2024-05-07 14:07:54.840 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-05-07 14:29:35.170 Update  Mduduzi
2024-05-07 17:17:06.160 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-05-07 17:41:46.097 Update  Mduduzi
2024-05-07 19:56:34.150 Insert  Vincent
2024-05-07 20:08:20.567 Update  Vincent
2024-05-07 21:21:44.183 Insert  Vincent
2024-05-07 21:32:25.117 Update  Vincent
2024-05-07 21:52:29.977 Insert  Vincent
2024-05-07 22:03:45.367 Update  Vincent
2024-05-07 23:41:22.010 Insert  Vincent
2024-05-07 23:59:01.577 Update  Vincent
2024-05-08 05:52:02.260 Insert  Vincent
2024-05-08 06:05:02.793 Update  Vincent
2024-05-08 07:51:46.623 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-05-08 08:06:40.530 Update  Mduduzi
2024-05-08 08:45:52.773 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-05-08 08:57:49.870 Update  Mduduzi
2024-05-08 12:30:23.743 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-05-08 12:45:48.367 Update  Mduduzi
2024-05-08 13:35:31.730 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-05-08 14:08:55.863 Update  Mduduzi
2024-05-08 14:03:53.623 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-05-08 14:21:42.327 Update  Mduduzi
2024-05-08 18:35:32.360 Insert  Vincent
2024-05-08 18:47:05.703 Update  Vincent
2024-05-08 20:28:08.123 Insert  Vincent
2024-05-08 20:51:11.737 Update  Vincent
2024-05-08 22:28:10.370 Insert  Vincent
2024-05-08 22:38:41.197 Update  Vincent
2024-05-09 08:06:12.537 Update  Elsie
2024-05-09 18:08:25.980 Update  Vincent
2024-05-08 23:10:51.037 Insert  Vincent
2024-05-08 23:22:56.150 Update  Vincent
2024-05-09 05:03:27.540 Insert  Vincent
2024-05-09 05:18:15.890 Update  Vincent
2024-05-09 08:04:56.753 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-05-09 08:22:35.880 Update  Mduduzi
2024-05-09 08:38:47.663 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-05-09 10:46:04.877 Update  Mduduzi
2024-05-09 12:20:36.157 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-05-09 12:32:53.570 Update  Mduduzi
2024-05-09 15:17:13.560 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-05-09 15:34:16.343 Update  Mduduzi
2024-05-09 17:01:35.117 Insert  Mduduzi
2024-05-09 17:41:49.690 Update  Mduduzi
2024-05-09 18:55:43.393 Insert  Vincent
2024-05-09 19:05:57.113 Update  Vincent
2024-05-09 21:01:47.810 Insert  Vincent
2024-05-09 21:16:20.430 Update  Vincent
2024-05-09 22:48:09.660 Insert  Vincent
2024-05-09 23:07:47.197 Update  Vincent
2024-05-10 00:07:57.497 Insert  Vincent
2024-05-10 00:26:49.397 Update  Vincent
2024-05-10 01:36:27.590 Insert  Vincent
2024-05-10 02:08:59.917 Update  Vincent
2024-05-10 11:23:45.437 Update  Elsie
2024-05-10 07:11:51.490 Insert  Reginald
2024-05-10 07:34:10.183 Update  Reginald
2024-05-10 09:39:32.560 Insert  Reginald
2024-05-10 09:53:33.040 Update  Reginald
2024-05-10 10:52:52.673 Insert  Reginald
2024-05-10 11:19:16.823 Update  Reginald
2024-05-10 14:03:31.497 Insert  Reginald
2024-05-11 11:27:47.107 Update  Reginald
2024-05-10 14:44:49.807 Insert  Reginald
2024-05-10 14:57:51.980 Update  Reginald
2024-05-10 15:46:02.270 Insert  Reginald
2024-05-10 15:52:42.310 Update  Reginald
2024-05-10 19:59:49.353 Update  Rebaone
2024-05-10 20:00:17.137 Update  Rebaone
2024-05-10 19:52:00.313 Insert  Vincent
2024-05-10 20:00:45.510 Update  Vincent
2024-05-10 21:11:47.857 Insert  Vincent
2024-05-10 22:24:58.827 Update  Vincent
2024-05-11 00:30:16.027 Insert  Vincent
2024-05-11 00:49:21.343 Update  Vincent
2024-05-11 08:44:57.017 Insert  Reginald
2024-05-11 16:02:01.043 Update  Reginald
2024-05-11 13:22:39.070 Insert  Reginald

// store proc
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetVisitorsTripSheetAuditReport] '2024-04-10', '2024-05-13'
(
    @StartDate  DATETIME,
    @EndDate    DATETIME
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @CurrentUser NVARCHAR(100);
    SET @CurrentUser = USER_NAME(); -- Get the current user

    SELECT DISTINCT
        VTA.Tripsheetno,
        VTA.Horse,
        VTA.Trailer,
        VTA.[Security] AS Username, -- Alias for clarity
        VTA.Driver,
        VTA.Station,
        ISNULL(VWTA.totalweight, VTA.TotalEntryWeight) AS TotalEntryWeight,
        ISNULL(VWTA.totalweight, VTA.TotalLeaveWeight) AS TotalLeaveWeight,
        VTA.DCheckWeight,
        VTA.VisTripdate,
        VTA.Tracktrip,
        VTA.DcheckTime,
        VTA.DCFullweight,
        VTA.UpdateDate,
        CASE 
            WHEN VTA.Operation = 'I' THEN 'Insert'
            WHEN VTA.Operation = 'U' THEN 'Update'
            ELSE 'Delete'
        END AS Operation,
        CASE 
            WHEN VTA.Username IS NULL THEN @CurrentUser -- Show real identity if Username is null
            WHEN VTA.Username = 'dbo' THEN @CurrentUser -- Show real identity if Username is 'dbo'
            ELSE VTA.Username
        END AS Username,
        VWTA.Customer,
        VWTA.Product,
        VWTA.totalWeight AS TotalWeight,
        VWTA.Purpose_code
    FROM 
        [dbo].[VisitorTripsheetAudit] VTA
    LEFT JOIN 
        [dbo].[VisitorWeighbridgeTicketAudit] VWTA ON VTA.Tripsheetno = VWTA.Trip
    WHERE 
        VTA.UpdateDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND DATEADD(SECOND, -1, DATEADD(DAY, 1, @EndDate)) -- Adjusted for end of the day
END


Try SUSER_SNAME() or ORIGINAL_LOGIN()

Have you read the differences between USER_NAME() and SUSER_NAME()? Which is VisitorTripsheetAudit recording?

@Charlieface which line from my store proc?

@AlwaysLearning no which what i need, can you show me where to apply this please. VisitorTripSheetAudit is a table store proc is inserting data into

if you only store dbo, how do you expect the code figure out the real user behind the mask? You can't go back in time, your procedure can never work, might as well just return random usernames

The best you can likely discern from the dbo is that it was actioned by a LOGIN that is either a sysadmin or maps to the database owner. If you have a lot of sysadmins, then it could be any one of them.

On the line SET @CurrentUser = USER_NAME();

@Charlieface thanks noted, it does now show username

you should probably go back and fix the trigger that logs the data. Either by getting the original username there, or if it's not possible, make the delete log into the auditing table, or if that's not possible either, expose the username through session context or whatever else so trigger can access is
